# Node.js Request GET returning raw data instead of JSON

Tags: json, node.js, rest, api, stackexchange-api

I have a particularly interesting issue, So I am trying to use Stackoverflow Search/Advanced API to query stackoverflow to get questions. I have tried it using PostMan and its returning JSON but in my Node.js application it is returning me raw data.

```
 exports.GetQuestions = function(query,requestify)
 {
   var request = require("request");

   var options = { method: 'GET',
     url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',
     qs: 
      { order: 'desc',
        sort: 'activity',
        site: 'stackoverflow',
        q: 'Error: Can\'t find Python executable 
 "C:\\Users\\harig\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.EXE", 
 you can set the PYTHON env variable' },
     headers: 
      { 'postman-token': 'b0b78842-94cd-a0b9-39cc-0e099136900c',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'Accept': 'application/json' } };

   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
     if (error) throw new Error(error);

     console.log(body);
   });
 }`
```

**I generated the code for the request using postman itself, I tried it on different API and the same code is working fine.**

I need help in figuring out how to get JSON as response.

Here is the response:

> cache-control: private
>   content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   content-encoding: gzip
>   access-control-allow-origin: *
>   access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST
>   access-control-allow-credentials: false
>   x-content-type-options: nosniff
>   date: Sun, 21 Jan 2018 16:12:19 GMT
>   connection: close
>   content-length: 4780

Here is a sample of data returned:

> ���������U����"�z�f%��-??ӵm��N�|�f&��fે�n�.""��DX�Ƀ�P��J�(�p�U�Q�N47 �1�M�.�|]�t5agA��0�rc �g�3��}
>   +�Y�q/�pL��M�RƜGwt�B��ڍ�@���9(>s��ʀ6�@�w���e/��Mu�ʮ��9,*�ML|
>   �s9�a���ߑW�r�[����ߗa�������a�~6��>ͦ����u�3���a�|P-�ᣖ�S'
>   �
>   �#v�D�PXM�i��ȹ��O�{2N�s��?
>   ����ڝ���O_������/   ���ř��M3��w�ܾ����g"��   ���$�(%"�r#S�Px3��;?4^}�܏�n�S�f7U[���g7�
>   a�cȩbҷ�Oq����X,8w�5Szp�P�y���rg�*<�������m�;�u���|��aXJ��!��~X�bK�#�b5���,)W+����)������+n[cl()�����lC>
>   okoSHcY��c\�TW0ƊLM
>   ��ݒ���oN9دhV���t�*�rj��
>   *�cPޝ�~l���E�́Ѳ�o3Dp�Eus侫��L��R�n��i�`+����DF���h $~377s=��W��xP��#�CAN�1�T�Ub0c$�e����S���&���B�}�~��Q�������m��m�������a�|���sL�Y;z8��T}�j~�]޽}���El�����]|��B�����*nt�^�,�����
>   k'
>   7�J�IO�i�d�m�4"�N���Ǳ��1䞦'�[�&�j���~�6�).G��v=��gn��x4�6nh�����V��o�)���^ಧ�2����['6����z� �#�/���J���j+vD�xƍ)N����qC[C���U��Z|�����vh*���_��>�gd�9��v���.��i�U�zJ��,�*J��RBt�s��iӮo��f�^A3��$�"7�N��!�l�b,"��96�@�������C���.��a�52'a�v�U��9��v]�l�~kΎ��ԌG�藊<9�eN;]t��n�k?;cu�  L�u}�t���q;৯��=�����Y��ZK������AL.�L

Comment: When you mentioned it as raw is it just string? Can you post example.If its just string what don't you use `Json.parse`.

Comment: Check content type of response to get better idea.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments guys, I have updated the question to include a sample of data being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you received is gzip compressed as shown by `content-encoding: gzip`.

Set `gzip:true` in your options.

```
var options = { method: 'GET',
    gzip: true,
     url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',
     qs: 
      { order: 'desc',
        sort: 'activity',
        site: 'stackoverflow',
        q: 'Error: Can\'t find Python executable 
 "C:\\Users\\harig\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.EXE", 
 you can set the PYTHON env variable' },
     headers: 
      { 'postman-token': 'b0b78842-94cd-a0b9-39cc-0e099136900c',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'Accept': 'application/json' } };
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked.